# How to use fundamerica API with PHP?

Tags: php, api, curl

I have been stuck on fundamerica API use with PHP. I know about curl and other staff but didnt get how to use this API with curl. The structure of the fundamerica API code is like this :-

```
<pre>
curl https://apps.fundamerica.com/api/entity_relationships \
-u 7Tft-uNlLJtgJezak2ywLINr7qHFa18i: \
-d child_entity_id='grYAoEvWT1WXtRt2uREvqg' \
-d description='Also a major stockholder.' \
-d parent_entity_id='H4XHtW7sSZua-55HdO-EiQ' \
-d parent_title= 'CEO'
</pre>
```

I didn't get how to use this code with php. You can see the documentation on the following URL: https://sandbox.fundamerica.com/support/documentation

Comment: "plz" ask a good question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to execute fundamerica API:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox.fundamerica.com/api/ach_authorizations/agreement_html");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");  


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "e_CdE6BtTcuqF2lAIqSEKa6vzl39U_EN:");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Accept: application/json');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: In CURLOPT_USERPWD Line before : is the api key and after : is password. and in fundamerica api password will always be blank..